# Logging Spring bean creation / dependency injection

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, log4j

I'm looking for a way to set up `Log4j` (or any other logger) so that I can see in log whenever Spring creates a bean or sets a bean property. Eg. something like this:

```
1:00:00 Creating bean Foo (Foo@ef5c94)
1:00:01 Creating bean Bar (Bar@147a87e)
1:00:02 Setting bean Foo (Foo@ef5c94) to Bar (Bar@147a87e)
(...)
```

Is this easily possible? I'm using `Spring 2.5.6` (no choice there :/ ) and `Log4j` (version doesn't matter I expect).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Looks like `org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory` logger is the best you can get.

Also simply try turning on *ALL* logging level for the whole `org.springframework` - maybe you'll find something more useful.

Comment: org.springframework.*=all did the trick in a WebSphere deployment

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Log4jConfigListener in your web.xml:

http://cristianvrabie.blogspot.com/2008/09/spring-commonslogging-and-log4j.html