# Get the beans created by Spring in logging

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, logging, log4j, log4j2

I'm new at logging stuff and I want to see the logging of spring, all the beans he creates, everything ...

I have try this code in my `log4j2.xml` but nothing happened (for my classes in `controller` package it's okey I got the log)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="INFO">

    <Appenders>
        <Console name="CONSOLE" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n" />
        </Console>
    </Appenders>

    <Loggers>

        <Root level="ALL">
            <AppenderRef ref="CONSOLE"/>
        </Root>

        <logger name="controller" level="ALL" />

        <logger name="org.springframework" level="ALL" />
        <logger name="org.springframework.*" level="ALL" />
        <logger name="org.springframework.**" level="ALL" />

    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

So in the classes of Spring they no contain something like `static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(...);` and `logger.debug(...);` or what !!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory
```

Also more info you can get from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6624610/logging-spring-bean-creation-dependency-injection)

Comment: I try it `<logger name="org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory" level="ALL" />` but got no log !!